# How to detect no internet connection on new tab in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I open a new tab with the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://website.com", active: true}, async tab => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, info) {
        if (info.status === 'complete' && tabId === tab.id) {
            // here my tab is loaded, but I don't know if it is
            // the requested website or the Chrome page that says "There is no Internet connection"
            // How can I find out?
        }
    });
});
```

How do I know if my tab loaded the requested page or is displaying the "There is no Internet connection" or Error 404 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `navigator.onLine` is `true`. If so, you are online and the page you requested has been correctly loaded, otherwise you are not, and the page which is being displayed is the "no internet connection" page.

As simple as this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://website.com", active: true}, async tab => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, info) {
        if (info.status === 'complete' && tabId === tab.id) {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                // Page correctly loaded.
            } else {
                // No internet connection.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip but won't work for me because this method doesn't detect 404 Error.

Comment: @Worker you didn't say anything about the 404 error in your question man... you said "I don't know if it us target URL or Chrome page that says connection is not available".